# JavaScript Async (callback) Sequence Formula Idea

Tags: javascript

I am trying to solve this problem: https://bigfrontend.dev/problem/implement-async-helper-sequence

I have a very manual code (only handle a fixed number of functions) that passes the tests:

```
    function sequence(funcs) {
        return (callback, num) => {
        funcs[0]((...args) => {
            const temp = args;

            if (args[0] instanceof Error) {
            callback(...args);
            return;
            }

            funcs[1]((...args) => {
            const temp = args;

            if (args[0] instanceof Error) {
                callback(...args);
                return;
            }

            funcs[2]((...args) => {
                const temp = args;

                if (args[0] instanceof Error) {
                callback(...args);
                return;
                }

                callback(...args);
            }, args[1]);
            }, args[1]);
        }, num);
        };
    }
```

Here is the complete jsfiddle code: https://jsfiddle.net/zfLd6koy/

Can someone help me turn my manual code into real code with a loop or reduce so it can handle any arbitrary number of functions?

Comment: No, a loop won't help here. Use recursion instead.

Comment: (Technically, `reduceRight` will work as well, but might be more complicated to understand)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Bergi for the hint. I am able to solve it using recursion:

```
function sequence(funcs) {
    return (callback, num) => {
      
      const helper = (idx, data) => {
        if (idx === funcs.length - 1) {
          funcs[idx]((...args) => {
            callback(...args);
            return;
          }, data);
          return;
        }
        funcs[idx]((...args) => {
          if (args[0] instanceof Error) {
            callback(...args);
            return;
          }
          helper(idx + 1, args[1]);
        }, data);
      };

      helper(0, num);
      
    }
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't even need the `helper`. Much easier to do the recursion in `sequence` itself, with `sequence(funcs.slice(1))` for the recursion. Notice that an empty `funcs` array should be the base case.